# How to search JSON string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

In my application which using web services and that web service method returns JSON string as follows,

```
[
   {
      "No":"21",
      "Area":"Default",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"1108",
            "Area":"Davie",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1107",
            "Area":"Ab region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1105",
            "Area":"Hollywood",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"219",
            "Area":"region116",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"24",
      "Area":"East11",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"211",
            "Area":"region108",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"218",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"1102",
            "Area":"region999",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "No":"25",
      "Area":"N25",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"213",
            "Area":"region110",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"220",
            "Area":"region999",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I used this JSON with [kendo treeview](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/filter-treeview-in-dialog). This works fine with PC devices. But with the huge JSON set(above JSON is part of huge set) `kendo treeview` getting the lagging problem with tab and mobile devices. currently this JSON, I directly bind with `kendo treeview`. But to reduce the lagging problem and increase efficiency I need to bind the JSON string to `kendo treeview` after filtration. Then I don't need to bind all this huge JSON and only bind relevant JSON. I think to achieve this I need to create another function to search/filter this huge JSON results. as an example, when the `search key = Hollywood` I need to return following JSON(**only relevant branch details and remove other parts "No":"1108" and "No":"1107"**)

```
[
   {
      "No":"21",
      "Area":"Default",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"1105",
            "Area":"Hollywood",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

eg: 2 when the `search key = East`, I need to return following JSON result.which means I **need to search Area value in both Root level and Branch level**

```
[
   {
      "No":"17",
      "Area":"East",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "No":"212",
            "Area":"region109",
            "IsValid":"False"
         },
         {
            "No":"219",
            "Area":"region116",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How to do that using `JQuery` function or another proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the job done

```
function FilterTree(arr, searchField, searchValue, subSearchField,  results, parentArr){
    for (var i=0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        if (arr[i][searchField] == searchValue) {
            if(parentArr === undefined) results.push(arr[i]);
            else parentArr[subSearchField].push(arr[i]);

        }else if(arr[i][subSearchField] !== undefined){
            var par = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr[i]))
                par[subSearchField] = []

            FilterTree(arr[i][subSearchField], searchField, searchValue, subSearchField,  results, par)
        }
    }       

    if(parentArr !== undefined && parentArr[subSearchField].length) results.push(parentArr)
    return results
    }
```

This will A) loop through the top-level. If a match is found it will be added to the results tree

B) If the top level has the specified child then the function will be called again with the child as the top level and the parent (OP) added to another array. Then if a match is found in the child it will be added to the OP before the OP is added to the results tree at the end of the loop

Example call:

```
FilterTree(tree, "Area", "Hollywood", "Branches", [])
```

Where "tree" is your original JSON object

Comment: Hi sir, I run your code as `FilterTree(tree, "Area", "Hollywood", "Branches", [])`. I pass the JSON object as a parameter. but it returns `[]` empty output

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is a fiddle of it working for me https://jsfiddle.net/ytqmr8jd/7/

Comment: Thanks sir,I'll check it How to avoid case sensitive for search key, which means when the searchkey = Default JSON return properly, but when the searchkey = default no value returning, because there **d** is simple. Have any solution to avoid this case sensitivity

Comment: Pass in lowercase variables and add ".toLowerCase()" to the end of the field variables in the if statements.`arr[i][...Field].toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest preparing a Kendo Data Source.
1) Read data into your data source using [transport](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport)

2) The kendo data source supports [filter operation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter)

3) Bind the data source to the tree view

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
      dataType: "jsonp" // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
    }
  },
  filter: { field: "ProductName", operator: "startswith", value: "Cha" }
});

  dataSource.fetch(function(){
  var view = dataSource.view();
   $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: view,
  dataTextField: "ProductName"
});
});
```

Comment: I'm using kendo, but the problem is with the huge data set **kendo getting a lagging problem with mobile and tab devices**. therefor I need to avoid that problem so trying to move this method

Comment: are you suggest that option for mobile and tab devices lagging problem?

Comment: I am a web developer so I do not know, if this will resolve your issue on mobile and tab devices. I merely suggested a solution of how you can display filtered data easily in your treeview.

Comment: Okay, Thanks anyway your suggestion. :)